# Datas put one on each other on chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In Chart.js cut last cell, so datas put one to each other. How can I fix it?
http://prntscr.com/eltpni

Here is my config

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: []
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {                              
                    displayFormats: {
                        quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
                    },
                }
            }]
        },
        responsive: false,
        maintainAspectRatio:false,
        legend: {
            display: false
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using a time scale? Can you post your chart.js config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide your chart config, I am assuming you are using a time  scale based on the posted image.

Unfortunately chart.js has trouble sometimes auto-fitting a time scale x-axis because of all the format variations and possibilities.  You can do one of two things to solve this.  Either expand the size of the chart container (so that there is more room to render the chart) or configure the time scale manually to optimize how it looks.

As an example, you could use the `time.unit` property to display the scale in units of 'second'.  Here is the relevant config:

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    gridLines: {
      display: false,
    },
    type: "time",
    time: {
      unit: 'second',
    }
  }]
}
```

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/aJqGGO) to demonstrate what I mean.

One thing to keep in mind though is that your configured unit needs to make sense with the data in your graph.  For example, if you try to use a time unit of `seconds` but you data spans multiple hours or day, then it will probably crash the page (because in that case chart.js tries to draw thousands of gridlines/ticks...one for each second)

Comment: Thanks, but when I put this option for xAxes the page hangs(( Maybe this because of datas format? I get them from JSON in seconds

Comment: Sorry, the data in that example spanned multiple days, so switching to `unit.second` makes it crash because chart.js is trying to render 1 axis tick for each second (across 5+ days).  See my updated codepen example in my answer.  I changed the data to be in the order of magnitude of 'seconds'

Comment: @TanyaMelnyk In addition to my above comment...make sure whatever time unit you use makes sense for your data.  If you have data points spanning multiple hours or day, then seconds won't be able to work.

Comment: @TanyaMelnyk What do you mean by "last whole column"?  Can you explain more about what you are wanting for that one?

Comment: Try using the time scale [`max` option](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale) and set the max to be a unit or 2 larger than your data.

Comment: Tank you very much. I've used  unitStepSize:5 and it made step wider